# android LinearLayout's size not fixed when using 'wieght' property

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to make android screen with three LinearLayouts. The parent LinearLayout's weightsum is 10 and I give child LinearLayout's weight as **( 1.5 , 7.5 , 1 )**
I thought LinearLayout's size would be fixed, but When I try to put some view elements in the child LinearLayouts, the child LinearLayout's size changes depending on the element inside.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/light_black"
    android:weightSum="10"
    tools:context=".userRegisterActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="7.5"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

if I  put TextView elements in the child LinearLayout, the sizes are changing... How to make it fix?

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer.
the `android:layout_height` property must be `'0dp'` not `match_parent`